# Passing data from property of subclass to BindableProperty not working in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui

I created a very simple `ContentView` that looks like this:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.TestComponent">
    <Label 
        Text="{Binding MyText}"
        TextColor="Black" />
</ContentView>
```

Code behind for this component looks like this:

```
public partial class TestComponent : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MyTextProperty =
                BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MyText), typeof(string), typeof(TestComponent), string. Empty);

    public string MyText
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(MyTextProperty);
        set => SetValue(MyTextProperty, value);
    }

    public TestComponent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

Here's where the data's coming from:

```
public class Student
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

and the `Teacher` object looks like this:

```
public class Teacher
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my `ContentPage`, I can display the student's name using this:

```
<controls:TestComponent MyText={Binding Name} />
```

But I can't display the teacher's name. It shows nothing. No errors either.

```
<controls:TestComponent MyText={Binding Teacher.Name} />
```

Anyone else had this problem? Am I doing something wrong here? BTW, when I inspect the data in my view model, I see that there's data in `Teacher` object.

P.S. Though it's not causing an issue, there's a second and minor problem: in VS 2022 17.6.5, XAML in my `ContentView` component is not seeing `MyText`. I get the dotted underline where I bind the `Label` to `MyText`. When I run it, it works fine though.

UPDATE: After stepping through the code, I discovered something. I use this `TestComponent` to render data in a `CollectionView`. Another important point is that I use a `Selector` to pick the correct component. So, I have multiple `ContentView`'s and the `Selector` picks the correct one depending on data.

Not sure what's causing this but I noticed that I get the correct data followed by `null` values. For example, if I have 4 items to display in my `CollectionView`, I hit the break point I place in my bindable property in the component 8 times.

So, I think the data come in but then get replaced with `null` values.

Any idea why?

Comment: if you use a `Label` instead of `TestComponent` does the binding work?

Comment: Actually, looks like data are coming through but are getting replaced with `null` values. See the UPDATE section in original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing piece was the `OnPropertyChanged`. I also gave my `Label` a name and assigned its text value in `OnPropertyChanged`. Here's what the XAML for my `ContentView` looks like now:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.TestComponent">
    <Label 
        x:Name="MyLabel1"
        TextColor="Black" />
</ContentView>
```

And here's what the `TestComponent` code behind looks like now:

```
public partial class TestComponent : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MyTextProperty =
                BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MyText),
                typeof(string),
                typeof(TestComponent),
                defaultValue: string.Empty,
                defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
                propertyChanged: OnMyTextPropertyChanged);

    public string MyText
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(MyTextProperty);
        set => SetValue(MyTextProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnMyTextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
       var control = (MyTestComponent)bindable;
       control.MyLabel1.Text = newValue.ToString();
    }

    public TestComponent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Last but not least, a special thank you to @GeraldVersluis as he covers this nicely in the following video. Although, that video covers the topic for Xamarin Forms, it applies to .NET MAUI perfectly!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbmoaD-PDtA

Comment: Maybe you want to checkout: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/. With this toolkit you dont have to write the Obersavble Pattern by yourself